# Creating a for loop in MQL4 that counts the bars

Tags: for-loop, mql4

So I am trying to make a for loop which counts 4 bars. Every bearish bar is negative and every bullish bar is positive. So the sum of all 4 bars should give me a number that is greater, less, or equal to 0. This I need to see the current price movement. This information is needed to enter a trade. What I want is after a trade is closed, that the for loop starts counting from this bar onwards. Because the problem I run into is that the program starts counting 5 bars after the trade closed giving false signals. How can I make the program count forward from the new bar?

```
for(int i = 5; i>0; i--){
  if(Open[i]>Close[i]){
     z = z - 1;
  }
  else if(Open[i]<Close[i]){
     z = z + 1;
  }
  else{
     z = z;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count back 5 bars from and including the current bar, then you would use the following code (note, there is no need for the z=z statement, it achieves nothing). You would have to make a function that returns the bar number for the last closed trade.

```
if(lastTradeClosed()==0)
{
   for(int i=0; i<=4; i++)
   {
      if(Open[i]>Close[i]) z--;
      else if(Open[i]<Close[i]) z++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, what I wanted to achieve was the ea to start the count again whenever is closed a trade. So for example, if it just closed a trade. It would count back again five bars. It would take the current bar as the first bar of the count. I hope I formulated my question clearly.

Comment: I've edited my answer further to your comment.